# Unable to install VLC on 12.04, have tried all the solutions posted on related questions

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, vlc

I really have tried a number of the solutions posted on similar questions, no matter what approach I attempt, I can only ever install the following packages:

```
ii  libvlc5                                    2.0.3+git20121229+r489-0~r41~precise1   multimedia player and streamer library
ii  libvlccore5                                2.0.3+git20121229+r489-0~r41~precise1   base library for VLC and its modules
ii  vlc-data                                   2.0.3+git20121229+r489-0~r41~precise1    Common data for VLC
ii  vlc-nox                                    2.0.3+git20121229+r489-0~r41~precise1   multimedia player and streamer (without X support)
```

I up until yesterday had the vlc player installed, but a failed attempt at installing skype removed a ton of packages from my system, vlc being one of them.

Here is a link to the captured output of whenever I run sudo apt-get install vlc:

https://gist.github.com/d43204060bf3fe0532c9

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is with libqtcore4, it has been updated to version 4.1, but a number of libqt libraries that depend on libqtcore4 are still depending on version 4.0. This most likely explains why vlc and virtualbox where removed from my system when I was hap-hazardly trying to install skype. I suppose a downgrade to libqtcore4 could work, is there any other solutions if I my assumption is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that libqtcore4 had been upgraded while a large number of libqt packages still depended on the previous version. The solution was to downgrade libqtcore4 and I was able to install VLC successfully after doing this. Here is a great post on downgrading packages in Ubuntu if you are facing a similar problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=321156

Answer (score 0):

VLC is in Ubuntu Software Centre it self. Open your Software Centre and type VLC in the search field. you will find it to install.

Comment: This has already been attempted by me, it gives me a different unmet dependencies error: https://gist.github.com/547951dbeea6bba89a69